# Windows Phone 8 Sockets: How can I access Simple TCP services on my home computer

Tags: sockets, tcp, windows-phone-8

I'm using this tutorial: [How to create and use a TCP socket client app for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202858%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), but am getting a `NotConnected` error message when attempting to access simple TCP services on my home computer. My WP8 and PC are on the same `WiFi` network. I've tried to connect using my public IP address and ports 7 (Echo) and 17 (Quote of the Day) with my firewall disabled, but still get nothing. [I have enabled simple TCP services.]

The pertinent part of the code seems to be in the MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using TCP_Client.Resources;

namespace TCP_Client
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
// Constants
const int ECHO_PORT = 7;  // The Echo protocol uses port 7 in this sample
const int QOTD_PORT = 17; // The Quote of the Day (QOTD) protocol uses port 17 in this sample 
/// <summary>
/// Handle the btnEcho_Click event by sending text to the echo server 
/// and outputting the response
/// </summary>
private void btnEcho_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear the log 
    ClearLog();

    // Make sure we can perform this action with valid data
    if (ValidateRemoteHost() && ValidateInput())
    {
        // Instantiate the SocketClient
        SocketClient client = new SocketClient();

        // Attempt to connect to the echo server
        Log(String.Format("Connecting to server '{0}' over port {1} (echo) ...", txtRemoteHost.Text, ECHO_PORT), true);
        string result = client.Connect(txtRemoteHost.Text, ECHO_PORT);
        Log(result, false);

        // Attempt to send our message to be echoed to the echo server
        Log(String.Format("Sending '{0}' to server ...", txtInput.Text), true);
        result = client.Send(txtInput.Text);
        Log(result, false);

        // Receive a response from the echo server
        Log("Requesting Receive ...", true);
        result = client.Receive();
        Log(result, false);

        // Close the socket connection explicitly
        client.Close();
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// Handle the btnEcho_Click event by receiving text from the Quote of 
/// the Day (QOTD) server and outputting the response 
/// </summary>
private void btnGetQuote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear the log 
    ClearLog();

    // Make sure we can perform this action with valid data
    if (ValidateRemoteHost())
    {
        // Instantiate the SocketClient object
        SocketClient client = new SocketClient();

        // Attempt connection to the Quote of the Day (QOTD) server
        Log(String.Format("Connecting to server '{0}' over port {1} (Quote of the Day) ...", txtRemoteHost.Text, QOTD_PORT), true);
        string result = client.Connect(txtRemoteHost.Text, QOTD_PORT);
        Log(result, false);

        // Note: The QOTD protocol is not expecting data to be sent to it.
        // So we omit a send call in this example.

        // Receive response from the QOTD server
        Log("Requesting Receive ...", true);
        result = client.Receive();
        Log(result, false);

        // Close the socket conenction explicitly
        client.Close();
    }
}

#region UI Validation
/// <summary>
/// Validates the txtInput TextBox
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if the txtInput TextBox contains valid data, otherwise 
/// False.
///</returns>
private bool ValidateInput()
{
    // txtInput must contain some text
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtInput.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter some text to echo");
         return false;
     }

    return true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Validates the txtRemoteHost TextBox
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if the txtRemoteHost contains valid data,
/// otherwise False
/// </returns>
private bool ValidateRemoteHost()
{
    // The txtRemoteHost must contain some text
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtRemoteHost.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a host name");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
#endregion

#region Logging
/// <summary>
/// Log text to the txtOutput TextBox
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message to write to the txtOutput TextBox</param>
/// <param name="isOutgoing">True if the message is an outgoing (client to server)
/// message, False otherwise.
/// </param>
/// <remarks>We differentiate between a message from the client and server 
/// by prepending each line  with ">>" and "<<" respectively.</remarks>
private void Log(string message, bool isOutgoing)
{
    string direction = (isOutgoing) ? ">> " : "<< ";
    txtOutput.Text += Environment.NewLine + direction + message;
}

/// <summary>
/// Clears the txtOutput TextBox
/// </summary>
private void ClearLog()
{
    txtOutput.Text = String.Empty;
}
#endregion

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Sample code to localize the ApplicationBar
            //BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
        }

        // Sample code for building a localized ApplicationBar
        //private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
        //{
        //    // Set the page's ApplicationBar to a new instance of ApplicationBar.
        //    ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        //    // Create a new button and set the text value to the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarIconButton appBarButton = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/appbar.add.rest.png", UriKind.Relative));
        //    appBarButton.Text = AppResources.AppBarButtonText;
        //    ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButton);

        //    // Create a new menu item with the localized string from AppResources.
        //    ApplicationBarMenuItem appBarMenuItem = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.AppBarMenuItemText);
        //    ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuItem);
        //}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual server running on your home PC to handle the QOTD and ECHO services?

Comment: According to this [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725973.aspx), I do. They were enabled using "Turn features on or off" in Control Panel. When I tried, using the same code, to connect to Port 80 (I believe this is the HTML port), the connection was successful.

Comment: You need a server app to receive and respond to the services. They're not built-in as part of Windows. You need a web server such as IIS or Apache, with either functionality enabled (specifically in that server) or modules loaded that handle those services. They're *web* services, not *computer* services; they've nothing to do with Windows Control Panel.

Comment: Well, or just a little applet that uses TcpListener.  These are not complicated protocols.  Don't forget to open the port on the firewall.

Comment: Thank-you. For me the important thing was implementing a WP8 socket. I listened with a Python echo server after opening an unassigned port. It works!